# Excel::Writer::XLSX adds an unexpected @ in formula

Tags: excel, perl, formula, xlsx, writer

I am writing a formula to an xlsx file using `Excel::Writer::XLSX`

```
use Excel::Writer::XLSX;
my $workbook  = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new( "test.xlsx" );
my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();
$worksheet->write( 'A1', "4");
$worksheet->write( 'A2', "=ERF.PRECISE(A1/SQRT(2))");
```

But when I open my Excel sheet, I can see in the cell

```
A2:
=@ERF.PRECISE(A1/SQRT(2))
```

Where does the `@` come from?

Comment: I tried this on Ubuntu. After generating the `.xlsx` with your script, I opened the `test.xlsx` in `libreoffice`. Here, the `@` character does not show, but the result for cell `A2` displays as `0` when it should be displayed as `0.99994`. If edit the formula for `A2`, for example deleting the `=` and then retyping it, and then press enter, the correct value is shown for `A2`. Very strange.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of -

```
$worksheet->write( 'A2', "=ERF.PRECISE(A1/SQRT(2))");
```

Use below method:

```
$worksheet->write( 'A2', "=_xlfn.ERF.PRECISE(A1/SQRT(2))");
```

Look into [the documentation for formulas for Excel 2010 and later](https://metacpan.org/pod/Excel::Writer::XLSX#Formulas-added-in-Excel-2010-and-later).

Complete Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Excel::Writer::XLSX;

my $workbook  = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new( "test.xlsx" );
my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();

$worksheet->write( 'A1', "4");
$worksheet->write( 'A2', "=_xlfn.ERF.PRECISE(A1/SQRT(2))");

$workbook->close();
```

**Output:**
[image: test.xlsx]