# Excel::Writer::XLSX adds an unexpected @ in formula (part 2)

Tags: excel, perl, formula, xlsx, writer

This question follows a first question :
[Excel::Writer::XLSX adds an unexpected @ in formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64684181/excelwriterxlsx-adds-an-unexpected-in-formula)

I am writing a formula to an xlsx file using `Excel::Writer::XLSX`

While I am using `_xlfn`, I do not have the expected result when I try to write a complex formula. Here is a code showing the issue:

```
use Excel::Writer::XLSX;
my $workbook  = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new( "test.xlsx" );
my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();
$worksheet->write( 'B1', "5");
$worksheet->write( 'A1', "4");
$worksheet->write( 'A2', "5");
$worksheet->write( 'A3', "3");
$worksheet->write( 'A4', "4");
$worksheet->write( 'A5', "6");
$worksheet->write( 'A7', "=_xlfn.STDEV.P(IF((A1:A5<B1),A1:A5))");
$workbook ->close();
```

Then the cell A7 contains: `=STDEV.P(IF((@A1:A5<B1),A1:A5))`

And because of the `@`, the cell shows `#NAME?` instead of the result of the formula.

Does anybody know how to remove this unexpected `@` ?

Comment: I'm leaving this here because I had no idea what the `@` could. Seems like a newish Excel feature, and something is going wrong. It's probably a _structured reference_: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-structured-references-with-excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e

Comment: Guessing it's the [implicit intersection operator](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/implicit-intersection-operator-ce3be07b-0101-4450-a24e-c1c999be2b34) actually.

Comment: Don't know anything about `xlsxwriter` but since this should be an array formula to begin with, maybe use: `"{=_xlfn.STDEV.P(IF((A1:A5<B1),A1:A5))}"`. If you'd scroll down to "Using the @ operator in new formulas" in the link @BigBen provided, you'd see what I think is happening in your case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks JvdV, the solution is indeed to use `{}`

```
use Excel::Writer::XLSX;
my $workbook  = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new( "test.xlsx" );
my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();
$worksheet->write( 'B1', "5");
$worksheet->write( 'A1', "4");
$worksheet->write( 'A2', "5");
$worksheet->write( 'A3', "3");
$worksheet->write( 'A4', "4");
$worksheet->write( 'A5', "6");
$worksheet->write( 'A7', "{=_xlfn.STDEV.P(IF((A1:A5<B1),A1:A5))}");
$workbook ->close();
```